# Changing UILabel title in custom UIButton without positional change

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I have a UIButton with the label on the left side and UIImageView on the right side. The button is used to open a UIPicker. When a value is picked in the picker the same value is shown in button title. When the title changes (or, more accurately, when to uilabel has a width that screws the UI up) the title and icon is moved and the UI does not look good.

When a title with too long text is used the word is clipped and when it's too short the alignment is messed up.

I've tried changing the label frame so it can be constant, whatever the text, and left aligning the text so the jumping stops. I added adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true which kind of works, but with a longer title the text will get too small. I've also tried recreating/rerendering the button when the title changes but all attempts fail.

```swift
lazy var sortButton = { () -> UIButton in
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sortButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        btn.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Sortera", comment: ""), for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.text = btn.titleLabel?.text?.uppercased()
        btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "ios-down"), for: .normal)

        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        btn.setTitleColor(Colors.FILTER_BUTTON_TEXT_COLOR, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Fonts.AkzidenzGroteskProMd, size: 16)
        btn.backgroundColor = Colors.BUTTON_BACKGROUND_GRAY
        btn.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        btn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 16, left: (btn.titleLabel?.frame.size.width)! - buttonInsideOffset/2, bottom: 16, right: -(btn.titleLabel?.frame.size.width)! + buttonInsideOffset/2)
        btn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -(btn.titleLabel?.frame.size.width)! + buttonInsideOffset, bottom: 0, right: (btn.titleLabel?.frame.size.width)! - buttonInsideOffset)
        return btn
    }()
```

I want all button to like like this, whatever the title text:
[image]

However, when the text is too small it looks like this:
[image]

or when it's too long:

[image]

Comment: When are you using the above code? Looks like a frame issue, try using it after the controller is visible. If the problem persists, remove btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  ( https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in many way but the simplest way :

Take a UIView and then others two-element (a label a imageView) set in this View and make it look like button then set constraint as you want. Then addTarget to label and do all functionality to that that target selector method.

Comment: Thanks! Removed the label and imageView from the button and created them separately and constrained them to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want button image to be shifted to the right or left then you have to constraint independent of the button's title label

```
     btn.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20) // Or any size you want

    // NB: I ommited left insets intentionally
    btn.imageEdgeInsets.top = 16
    btn.imageEdgeInsets.bottom = 16
    btn.imageEdgeInsets.right = 16
```

Then constraint your label dependent to the imageView position, that way only label size will change without affecting the position of image.

```swift
btn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -(btn.titleLabel?.frame.size.width)! + buttonInsideOffset, bottom: 0, right:   btn.imageView?.frame.width + 10)
```

Lastly, Since the frame is fixed size, I think you need to limit the font scaling factor to the min size you want and truncate the tail when that size is reached. If you don't want to truncate tail then you have to enable multiline titleLabel (Which I think you don't want this).

```
    btn.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5 // Or whatever minimum scale you wish
    btn.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail // Since button size is fixed and you want to limit font size then the best option is to truncate tail
```